# Enviar SMS utilizando android

Tags: android, android-studio

tenho uma aplicação e gostaria que ele enviasse um sms para o próprio celular mas não estou conseguindo, não da erro apenas não envia.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("987654321", null, "Texto SMS", null, null);
```

Este é o trecho que tenho, o que fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar um SMS de forma programática no Android é necessário adicionar o uso da permissão no manifesto `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`. Se você estiver desenvolvendo para a versão 6.0 ou superior, precisa fazer uso das [Solicitações de Permissão em Tempo de Execução](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=pt-br).

Após se certificar de que possui permissão para enviar as mensagens, verifique o número que está enviando. Utilize o código de país (`+55`), DDD e o número do celular contendo todos os dígitos.

Comment: Já tinha adicionado a permissão no manifesto, estou usando a versão 4.3.
E o número está assim +55 81 987654321. e mesmo assim não está enviando.

Comment: Existem quaisquer informações no logcat? Se possível, tente incluir na pergunta um trecho contendo possíveis registros do app/sistema. Adicionar chamadas de log antes e depois do teste de envio ajudam a delimitar os logs.

Comment: Resolvido, testei em uma versão superior a 6 e tive que colocar a solicitação de permissão.

Comment: Ótimo! Não esqueça de marcar a pergunta como resolvida :)

Comment: como marcar como resolvida?

Comment: No canto superior esquerdo do quadro com a minha resposta existe uma marcação (check). Ao clicar nele, o mesmo ficará verde e a resposta será marcada como solução para a pergunta.